# How to map a class attribute using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-mapping

When I try to map the Phone on a Phone in the Contact class it gives the following error:

> Initial creation of the SessionFactory object failed. Error: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.livro.capitulo3.crudannotations.Telephone, at table: contact, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column (numPhone)]
>   Error closing insert operation. Message: null
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   The mapping class is as follows:

//Class Contato

```
package com.livro.capitulo3.crudannotations;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.ManyToAny;

@Entity
@Table(name = "contato")
public class ContatoAnnotations {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "codigo")
    private Integer codigo;

    @Column(name = "nome", length = 50, nullable = true)
    private String  nome;

    @Column(name = "telefone", length = 50, nullable = true)
    private String  telefone;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 50, nullable = true)
    private String  email;

    @Column(name = "dt_cad", nullable = true)
    private Date        dataCadastro;

    @Column(name = "obs", nullable = true)
    private String  observacao;


    //Como ficaria a annotation aqui???? Só vou persistir esta tabela
    @OneToMany
    private Telefone numTelefone;
    ...
    //Getters e Setters

}
```

//Class Telefone:

```
package com.livro.capitulo3.crudannotations;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "contato")
public class Telefone {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "numero")
    private String numero;
    @Column(name = "tipo")
    private String tipo;

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

}
```

I do not know how to do this mapping. Help! Thanks!!!

Comment: Please ask questions in English.

Comment: Excuse! Fixed! It was the hurry!

Comment: Why do you map both entities to the same table `contato`? It should be 2 different tables.

Comment: The idea is to map only to the contact table.

Comment: If you want to map two entities to the same table than read this question, there is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007676/how-to-map-two-hibernate-entities-on-the-same-database-table

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@OneToMany` annotation, it should be some collection like `List` or `Set`:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "contacto")
private List<Telefone> numTelefone = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also change the table name for `Telephone` entity, it must be different than `contacto`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tel")
public class Telefone {...}
```

Comment: Can I not map a class phone?

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not mapped it properly. There are several ways how to do it: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany