# Hibernate - how to load different view of same object

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

How is this called and how to solve my next problem on API. I have to return same object with different views. Some data should not be returned to user. Here is example:
Parent:

```
public class OrginalObject{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;
    private String school;
    private String secret;
    private Address Address;
```

child:

```
public class Address{
    private int id;
    private String street;
    private String zipCode;
    private String Country;
```

If i want to load list of complete objects i would call:

```
session.createCriteria(OrginalObject.class).list();
```

1.) But if don't want someone to know my property secret, i need to hide it. But i don't know how to call it from database the way it would have every other property. Something like:

```
session.createCriteria(OrginalObjectPublic.class).list();
```

2.) Also I would like to have option to load only "important" data. That means only properties `id, name, school`.

```
session.createCriteria(OrginalObjectImportant.class).list();
```

Is there a way to do an adapter/"custom view" to directly load it from database? I know i can write pure sql, but i would like to use it on objects with 20+ properties that have nested lists/objects.

3.) Also how to use this transformation to load only few properties of nested object with those from orginal. Example json (only id, name, school from OrginalOBject and id, street from Address:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "testname",
    "school": "testschool",
    "Address": {
    {
        "id": 33,
        "street": "testStreet 33"
    }
}
```

4.) also how to use it on nested Lists if Address would be array:

```
public class OrginalObject{
    ...
    private List<Address> AddressList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since hibernate is a persistence-framework and you can not save/persist to a view, this is not possible. Yes you can make a view having the name like the table and preferr the view but you will not be able to store to that entity anymore.

1. You can remove the getter (getSecret) from the entity. So the database still have the field but your entity is not aware of it. This may cause problems if you try to store data using that entity, you may not be able to set the secret.
2. You can make the getter default (package-level-access) and seal the package to let noone else than the sealed projects access the getter.
3. You can use [spring's method authorization mechanism](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

Comment: Thanks. I just need it for read. I did not know that i can have entities with same names. Will try it

Answer (score 1):

First no one have access to your secret, 
only you the programmer who is supposed to see it.
Second if no one is supposed to have it why store it.
And if you want to pull it out you can use inheritance.
something like

```
public abstract PublicObject {
    ...
}

public OriginalObject extends PublicObject {
    String secret;
}
```

Edit:
2nd & 4th questions you can solve them with hql:

```
String hql = "SELECT O.id, O.name, O.school FROM OrginalObject O";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

as for your 3th question it depends on your api. if you're using jackson for example you can use `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add in the discription it is on API. So i can return different views to user. will edit now..

Answer (score 1):

You can map more than one entity to the same table, each one with the set of properties you want to expose.
Take a look to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007676/how-to-map-two-jpa-or-hibernate-entities-on-the-same-database-table)