# Spring Boot Entities(Too Big Object)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA(Hibernate) with Spring Boot

I have two database tables. First is Course Table & second is Institute Table.
Both tables have around 20 Columns.

Now My Course Table has one column named parent_id, which is the id of Institute Table.

I have designed my two entities specifying the JOIN Columns and the data is also fetched and my object is ready.

But the issue is I donot want complete institute object inside course object, I just want institute id(listing_id) & name. How do I desigm my entities.

**Course Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="courses")
public class Course implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name="course_id")
    private int courseId;

    private String status

    .. Other Properities...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="listing_id",insertable=false,updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="status", referencedColumnName="status",insertable=false, updatable=false),
      })
    @Where(clause="status='live'")
    private Institute institute;

    .. Getters & setters

}
```

**Institute Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="institutes")
public class Institute implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name="listing_id")
    private int listingId;

    private String status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="institute")
    private List<Course> Courses;

    .. Other Properties

    .. Getters & Setters

}
```

Comment: On which level do you want only the "light" institute object? On the entity level or when the entities are serialized to JSON and returned in the REST API?

Comment: On the Entity Level, when the entities are actually getting created. Also I would love to know how to do when the entities are serialized to JSON and returned in the REST API(just for my learning purpose).

Comment: If you only want certain fields in your entity, just remove all other fields which you don't want. Regarding JSON serialization: Have a look at the `@JsonView` annotation.

Comment: I cannot remove them from Institute Entity as I am using Institute Object separately at different place. Only when I am fetching Course Object, then I need light institute object. Can it be done using Projections some how?by creating a separate Institute Projection & use it?

Comment: You can map two entity classes to the same table - one containing full information and the other only summary information (`id` and `name` if you want). Then, you can mark the entity containing only summary information as `@Immutable` so that the underlying table cannot be changed through its instances. Finally, map both entities to the associated entity with lazy loading and use whichever one is appropriate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to map two JPA or Hibernate entities on the same database table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007676/how-to-map-two-jpa-or-hibernate-entities-on-the-same-database-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a CourseDTO object.

```
public class CourseDTO {
  private int listingId;
  private String name;

  Get and set method ...
}
```

The Institute entity have many Courses.You can select a pojo. ex,

```
@Query("select new com.pakcage.name.CourseDTO(c.id, c.courseId, i.listingId, i.name) from Course c join Institute i where c.id=:id")
public CourseDTO fetchCourse(@Param("id") Long id);
```